# Timeout or duplicate return from reCAPTCHA on symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, recaptcha

I added google's reCAPTCHA to my register page in my symfony 3 project via this bundle: [github/EWZRecaptchaBundle](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle). After submiting the register form I have this:

```
$api_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";

$secret_key = "----my-key----";

$api_key = "&secret=" . $secret_key;

$g_recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$api_response = "&response=" . $g_recaptcha_response;

$api_remote_ip = "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$url = $api_url . $api_key . $api_response . $api_remote_ip;

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
```

The responde giv me this:

```
array(4) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2017-07-06T16:49:56Z" ["hostname"]=> string(14) "********.com" ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "timeout-or-duplicate" } }
```

This **timeout-or-duplicate** isn't documented in their guide. I have no idea how to fix this or where does it come from.

Comment: One can check this also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678256/google-recaptcha-response-success-false-no-error-codes/45659347#45659347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesnt this bundle do this for you already (check captcha and set form to valid or invalid),   hence, making your custom call,   a **duplicate** or timeout ...  (since it is already done by the bundle on bindRequest (i think) )

Comment: yep, the bundle does it for me